# Retrieving notification intent to redirect user to specific activity of the application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-pendingintent

I am making an application that gathers push notifications with NotificationListenerService in Android.
Retrieving notification contents such as the name of the app, contents of the app, package name, notification registered time etc. works very well.
However, when trying to retrieve notifications Intent that redirects the user to a specific Activity of an app when clicked, doesnt work. It won't get Intent. What might be the problem?

```
try {
            //ne.cls_intent = getIntent(sbn.getNotification().contentIntent).toString();
                ne.cls_intent =getIntent(notification.contentIntent).resolveActivity(pm).getClassName();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                ne.cls_intent = "No Intent";
    }
```

Comment: Are you Saying you are unable to redirect to specific activity when clicked on Notification? @Hyeon

Comment: @BrahmaDatta yes

Answer (score 0):

Try this, @Hyeon

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Your_Desired_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Key", value); //for sending data to your specific activity if needed.
            
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), (int) (Math.random() * 100), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

           NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "101";

            //TODO - make the title BOLD - change the notification icons
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(message_push)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)
                    .setContentText(event_title_push)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setColor(getColor(R.color.text_color))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
                channel.setDescription(event_title_push);
                // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
                // or other notification behaviors after this
                mNotificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                channel.setImportance(importance);
                mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
                mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
            assert mNotificationManager != null;

            // Cancel the notification after the particular notification gets selected
            mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            
            mNotificationManager.notify((int) (Math.random() * 100) /* Request Code */, mBuilder.build());
```

This is the total working of showing the notification with title and vibrate and also redirecting to a specific activity.